# Why is my track/ramp unusable?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've constructed a track/ramp in DF v0.34.10, but it shows as "Unusable".  I've tried building it the other direction (E/W) several times, but to no avail.  **How can I build a usable track/ramp in this situation?**

View from above:

```
xxxxxx
Strttt
xxxxxx
```

View from the side

```
xxxxxx
xxdttt
Stu xx
xxxxxx
```

- `S` stop
- `t` track
- `r` ramp (from above)
- `u` upward ramp
- `d` downward ramp
- `x` stone
- (space) space

Comment: A legend would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramps are tricky to get right. In a nutshell, the space below the floor you want the ramp to lead up to can't be open space, it has to be a wall (constructed or natural).

If I'm reading your diagram right (A legend or a prtsc picture would be wonderful), you've got open space on all 4 directions next to your up-ramp. Fill that square in with a constructed wall (the blank spot on the 2nd diagram) and it should work.

Comment: Rebuilt next to the existing wall and that worked, thanks!